# How do I add to my snake using Java?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to make a snake game for my final project in my programming class. I am trying to add to the snake using an array, since using an array of objects is one of the requirements for the project. But I can't figure out how to make it work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.applet.*;

    public class FinalApplet extends Applet implements KeyListener {
         private Image grass;
         private Image mouse;
         private Snake[] mySnake = new Snake[100];
         private int x;
         private int y;

         public void init() {
            grass = getImage(getCodeBase(), "grass.jpg");
            mouse = getImage(getCodeBase(), "mouse.png");
            addKeyListener(this);
         }
        public void update (Graphics g) {
            paint(g);
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Image buffer  = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
            Graphics z = buffer.getGraphics();
            z.drawImage(grass, 0, 0, this);
            z.drawImage(mouse, 200, 130, this);
            z.setColor(Color.RED);
            z.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
            g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 y = y + 1;
                 repaint();
             }
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                y = y - 1;
                repaint();
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                x = x - 1;
                repaint();
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                 x = x + 1;
                 repaint();
            }
       }
       public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
       }
       public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
       }
```

}

Comment: How could anyone answer this without seeing the `Snake` class? Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: The snake class has nothing in it, since I'm not sure what to do with it. It just kind of exists

Comment: I don't think your question is clear. Do you want to make the array bigger? Is your snake's max length == to mySnake.length? Does your snake have an initial length of 1? Could you please show the code you have where you have tried to make your snake bigger, please?

Comment: You really don't need a snake class. Represent the snake as an array holding the coordinates where it's elements are supposed to be right now. Be sure to have the array at the max_size of your snake. When doing a step push all the indices "back" and add the new coordinate.

Comment: You have to elaborate your code to get a very good answer. But keep this in mind, you cannot expand OR add to a java array. Instead you could use a `List<E>`.

Comment: Sorry it isn't clear, I am not sure how to explain it since I am so confused by it. I can remove the snake class, that's easy. The part I am struggling with is that I am trying to add to the snake each time it eats the mouse. Each segment of the snake is part of the array. I think I need to use a for loop, but I am not sure. Right now, the array is null since it hasn't been assigned a value

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your snake starts with at least a length of 1, for it to be shown. That means that your array in its first element has a starting coordinate. All other cells of the array are empty (or `null` whichever you are using) and hence should not be painted on your canvas, i.e. should not be shown to your user.
A solution could be that every time your snake moves, you update each cell of your array (taking into account that each cell is a section of your snake) with its new position.
When the snake overlaps with the position of a "mouse" then the next available cell on your array should have the last position of your last (now before last) cell, taking into account that it should not move until its previous cell has moved and that only cells that have an actual value should be painted.
I hope this helps, but you should try and post more code so we could help with specific programming problems.